# cuDNN Error Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have installed Anaconda with Python 3.8 and CUDA 10.1 with CUDNN 8.0.3 on my Window 10 with GPU GTX 1050. But Still I get the error [image: Details of the Error]

Comment: Do you have other kernels running? Close PyCharm, Spyder, or other Jupyter tabs, and don't forget to shutdown all other kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having a similar issue with TF 2.3.1. However, right away I can tell you that your cudnn version is incompatible. Only cudnn 7.6 is supported with the latest TF which as of right now is 2.3.1. See compatibility link below.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements